# Why does "0 && true" return 0 in javascript instead of a boolean?

Tags: javascript

I was convinced that any logical expression in Javascript will return a boolean value, yet this expression returns a number 0 instead of a bool:

```
0 && true
> 0
```

Why is that so? How do I approach logical expressions in Javascript in this case to prevent this kind of mistake in the future?

Background story - I was baffled by this statement in jQuery:

```
$('.something').toggle(0 && true);
```

It doesn't toggle the element because '0' is returned, and not a boolean!

Maybe there are some clever reasons why this is so, but can't say I like it.

Comment: The logical operators in JavaScript do [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: you can do !!0 to convert it to a boolean

Comment: what about `Boolean(whatever complex expression you want)`  ... i.e. in your case `Boolean(0 && true)` - not only will it result in a Boolean, it's "self documenting" - *here there be a Boolean, let no one be mistaken*

Comment: Is this a mistake, though? Seems like a design decision.

Comment: Can you show an example where it would be a mistake? Without a complete example it is hard to tell how to do that in the correct way. `0 && true`evaluates to `0` because `0` is the first [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) part of the expression, so it would work correctly in case of an `if` clause.

Comment: Well, imagine doing something like $('.something').toggle(0 && true); I always assumed it returns a bool, but when it returns 0, it changes meaning of that method call.

Comment: @JaromandaX A mistake implies an oversight rather than something intentional, which seems to be the case here. Is OP going to prefix all conditionals in JS with `!!()` going forward?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I am. In your example the _"failure"_ point is the comparison not the if clause. A `if(a)` or an `if(!a)` would work.

Comment: @Tool yes in case where the API descides what action has to be done base on the type of the passed value, then this will be definitely a problem. Especially when - like in the case of jquery toggle -  it could be a boolean or a numeric value. So in such a case you would either need to use the `!!(0&&true)` or the `Boolean(0&&true)` approach.

Comment: @t.niese yes I'd argue that `.toggle` is the problem rather than JS, since it accepts all sorts of values. If you pass in a boolean, you either show or hide the element. Passing in a number sets a delay. Passing a string will be treated as being a number. Passing an object will be treated as if it's settings. Passing `undefined` will be akin to invoking just `.toggle()` with no arguments. A function will be executed after completion. I don't know what happens if you pass in `null` - presumably it'd be treated as `false`...or an object. It's convoluted.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The documentation about the `&&` operator says:

> `expr1 && expr2`: Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to `false`; otherwise, returns `expr2`.

This is why is returns the first value: `0`

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description

You expected as a result `false` (a boolean), however the boolean value of the resulting value is falsy too. This means that you can use it in a condition (`if`) and have the expected behavior.

If you need to store it in a variable and prefer to have a boolean value, you can convert it. This can be done using a double negation: `!!`

`!!(0 && true)`

Or using `Boolean`:

`Boolean(0 && true)`

Comment: you don't explain how to *prevent this mistake*

Answer (score 3):

As @Maxime Chéramy noted, JavaScript checks if the first element returns false and it doesn't really check the second one. This saves calculation time.

JS does not need to check both statements if the first is false it will not check the second one, it will just return the first one. If the first is true, again, it doesn't check the second one, it just returns it.

A number, object, array, or string are truety.

Use Boolean() to get a Boolean value or use the short method !!()

```
'banana' && true  // returns true
```

but

```
true && 'banana' // returns 'banana'
Boolean(true && 'banana') // returns 'true'
!!(true && 'banana') // returns 'true'
```

with three

```
true && 'banana' && 1 // returns 1
true && 1 && 'banana' // returns 'banana'
1 && 'banana' && true // returns true
Boolean(true && 'banana' && 1) // returns 'true'
!!(1 && 'banana' && true) // returns 'true'
```

Comment: I think OP knows how it works ... wants to know how to "prevent" such a mistake

Comment: I don't know OP knows how it works, or they probably wouldn't have asked the question as is. Also, even if *OP* knows that, what about somebody else who stumbles upon the question?

Comment: Edited. Thank you :)